# ¿Alguien sabe como conectarse a la api de Rithmic trader con laravel?

Tags: laravel, api

Estoy desarrollando un proceso de automatización de credenciales y me pidieron que se conectara con Rithmic trader, ando buscando su documentación y lo que encontré no indica la ruta o el API a donde enviar los datos.

Si alguien ha trabajado anteriormente con esta plataforma sería de mucha ayuda si cuenta con alguna documentación u orientación.

Comment: si, seguramente la gente de rithmic trader tienen idea, ya averiguaste en su pagina?

Comment: Sí, la documentación que brindan no explica mucho (no indican el endpoint a donde mandar los datos)

Comment: y que has intentado hasta el momento?